# How to pause a CSS keyframe animation when it ends the first cycle?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm working on my first CSS keyframe animation and would like to know how it would be possible to pause an animation after it finishes its first run-through. You can check out my site here: http://www.tommaxwell.me and the grey quote at the bottom has a hover animation that you can see. However, once the animation is over it resets. How should I go about stopping it so that it stays in the end state of the animation when it's finished?

I know the use of a keyframe animation in this case is kind of lame and unnecessary, but I'm really just testing out keyframes, and will use it better later. :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Animations are not transitions. Even though your answer suggests using transitions, they're not the same thing.

Comment: @BoltClock ya I am aware of that, that's why I suggested him to use transitions for what specific effect he is trying to achieve here using animation which is not required here, he wants to preserve the hovered state I guess

Comment: @Mr.Alien: You're tagging based on the answer, which isn't the right way to do it. Only tag based on the question.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh yes sorry, I added css3 and transitions too where I was suppose to only tag css3 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what you are doing here, use CSS `transition` instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hFWsW/)

```
.class {
   color: #ff0000;
   transition: color 2s;
   -moz-transition: color 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition: color 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition: color 2s; /* Opera */
}

.class:hover {
   color: #00ff00;
}
```

You wont be able to preserve the hovered state of your text, for that you need to use JavaScript

Comment: Great, thanks! I think I understand the difference between the two now.

Answer (score 7):

As @Mr. Alien answered, transitions is to prefer for this, but since you asked - it is possible to maintain the last state in an animation.

You do this by adding `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NsSYJ/2/)

Here's the code from my example:

HTML

```
<div class="text">Hover here</div>​
```

CSS

```
.text {
  color: blue;  
}

.text:hover {
    -webkit-animation: color 1.0s ease-in forwards;
       -moz-animation: color 1.0s ease-in forwards;
         -o-animation: color 1.0s ease-in forwards;
            animation: color 1.0s ease-in forwards;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes color {
  0%   { color: blue; } 
  100% { color: red;  }
}

@-moz-keyframes color {
  0%   { color: blue; } 
  100% { color: red;  }
}

@-o-keyframes color {
  0%   { color: blue; } 
  100% { color: red;  }
}

@keyframes color {
  0%   { color: blue; } 
  100% { color: red;  }
}
```

Here's a good resource if you want to read about the the ‘animation-fill-mode’ property.
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations/#animation-fill-mode-property

Comment: I don't know why the accepted answer got all the upvotes because Chistofer was the one who actually answered question.